# ng-tab content in module

Tags: angular, tabs, components, ng-bootstrap

I have the next situation, i have a UserProfileComponent with the tab structure and i want add the tabs from diferents modules.

UserProfileComponent.html

```
<ngb-tabset>
   <ngb-tab>
      <app-user-profile-history></app-user-profile-history>
      <another-tab></another-tab>
   </ngb-tab>
 </ngb-tabset>
```

app-user-profile-history.html

```
<ng-template ngbTabTitle>History</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
       <p>text</p>
</ng-template>
```

the components are declared in the main module.
Main module

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { HistoryComponent } from './user-profile/history/history.component';
import { AnotherTabComponent } from './user-profile/another-tab/another-tab.component';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     CommonModule,
     NgbModule.forRoot()
   ],
   declarations: [
      UserProfileComponent,
      HistoryComponent,
      AnotherTabComponent]
   })
```

But the content are not shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app-user-profile-history` should be declared as any other component(you don't need `ngTabTitle` `ngTabContent`)

then in your tabset:

```
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="User profile history">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-user-profile-history></app-user-profile-history>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab> 
  <ngb-tab title="Another tab">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <another-tab></another-tab>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Comment: oh, i have the same code but i think maybe there are a 'cleaner way'